# Uncaught Error: Invalid date format.(format: 'LT') bootsrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, datetimepicker, timepicker, uncaught-exception

I want to have only time picker in `datetimepicker`

I have tried using following code

```
$(function () {  
        $('.datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
            format: 'LT'
        });
    });
```

but it gives following error

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid date format.
    at Object.parseFormat (bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js:1)
    at new g (bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js:1)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js:1)
    at Function.each (vendor.js:374)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (vendor.js:139)
    at jQuery.fn.init.d.fn.datetimepicker (bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js:1)
    at HTMLDocument.eval (eval at globalEval (vendor.js:328), <anonymous>:4:31)
    at fire (vendor.js:3099)
    at Object.add [as done] (vendor.js:3145)
    at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.ready (vendor.js:3378)
```

I want time picker to be worked as:

[image: expected datetimepicker]

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

i have traced the problem , it was simple.

just needed to place bootsrap js file after jquery and before all js files.

thats it it solved my problem

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this format "dd/M/yyyy"